# iTerm2 - zsh - keep history of commands when opening a new pane

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm, zsh, history

with `zsh` on `MacOS Catalina`, when I split my current window of `iTerm2` by opening a new pane, I would like to be able to keep in this new pane the history of commands of previous pane (which is still opened).

Here my current config into `~/.zshrc` :

```
# History
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
HISTSIZE=10000000
export SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
# Avoid duplicates
#setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
# Remove duplicates in history
function remove_duplicates() {
   echo "$(history 0 | sort -k2 -k1nr | \
   uniq -f1 | sort -n | cut -c8-)" > $HISTFILE
}
remove_duplicates();
setopt inc_append_history

# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend
```

What is missing or what did I do wrong in this config ?

and Just a question : when I open a new pane, did `~/.zshrc` file is executed (I mean sourced like `source ~/.zshrc`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To share history between sessions, you need to use the `SHARE_HISTORY` option.  Additionally, you will want to *append,* rather than overwrite your history file.

```
setopt SHARE_HISTORY
setopt APPEND_HISTORY
```

Per the ZSH documentation ([Chap. 16 - Options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html)) you should also disable `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`.

> This option both imports new commands from the history file, and also causes your typed commands to be appended to the history file (the latter is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY, which should be turned off if this option is in effect). The history lines are also output with timestamps ala EXTENDED_HISTORY (which makes it easier to find the spot where we left off reading the file after it gets re-written).

There's also a few other commands that you may be interested in to deal with your dupes:

- `HIST_NO_STORE` - removes the `history` command from history.
- `HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS` - deletes an older version of added commmand
- `HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS` - when saving the history file, older commands that duplicate newer ones aren't saved