# MacOS Catalina terminal tab doesn't remember its own previous commands

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

I upgraded from El Capitan to Catalina recently; when I click <kbd>↑</kbd> in any terminal tab it used to toggle previous commands executed within that specific tab only, but now it will show commands for all tabs which is very annoying

Is there any setting to fix that?

Comment: Are you using Zsh or Bash? Type `echo $SHELL` or `echo $0`

Comment: If you’re using Zsh you want to *unset* the history options detailed in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390987/119271)

Comment: @mzoz : A **tab** itself does not remember anything. The shell does. You can configure zsh to either have one common history or a separate history for each interactive zsh process.

Comment: Have a look at the manpage, where the options `sharehistory` , `incappendhistory`, `histnostore`, and the variables `HISTFILE` and `SAVEHIST` are discussed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question regards how the shell maintains its command history. In switching from El Capitan, to Catalina, you may have also switched your default shell from `bash` to `zsh`, and these shells have different defaults for maintaining their command history. This answer assumes your question is for altering the behavior of the `zsh` command history.

You have at least two choices:

1. Restore `bash` as your shell:

   ```
   % chsh -s /bin/bash
   ```

   This is easily changed if you decide to return to `zsh`:

   ```
   chsh -s /bin/zsh
   ```
2. Configure `zsh` to disable the "aggregation" of command histories [see `APPEND_HISTORY`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History)

   From `man zshoptions`:

   > APPEND_HISTORY 
   > If this is set, zsh sessions will append their history list to  the  history  file,  rather than replace it. Thus, multiple parallel zsh sessions
   > will all have the new entries from their history lists added to the  history  file, in the order that they exit.  The file will still be periodically re-written to trim it when the number of lines grows 20% beyond the value specified by $SAVEHIST (see also the HIST_SAVE_BY_COPY option).

   Accordingly, if you wish to continue using `zsh` as your shell, you can ***un-set*** the `APPEND_HISTORY` option, and the command histories from your various terminals/shells will not be aggregated into a single history.

   You can check to see which options are set or unset as follows:

   ```
   % setopt
   ...
   # lists options that are set

   % unsetopt
   ...
   # lists options that are unset

   % set -o
   ...
   # lists all options w/ off/on status
   ```

   NOTE: `setopt` only prints the options not enabled by default. The APPEND_HISTORY option is set by default - as designated by the **`<D>`** seen in the man page excerpt above.

   Now, this is a bit obtuse (IMO at least), but notice that there is an option appearing in the `unsetopt` output named `noappendhistory`. This is explained in the [zsh Options documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Option-Aliases) as follows:

   > In the following list, options set by default in all emulations are marked ; those set by default only in csh, ksh, sh, or zsh emulations are marked , , ,  as appropriate. When listing options (by ‘setopt’, ‘unsetopt’, ‘set -o’ or ‘set +o’), ***those turned on by default appear in the list prefixed with ‘no’***. Hence (unless KSH_OPTION_PRINT is set), ‘setopt’ shows all options whose settings are changed from the default.

   (emphasis mine)

   It comes down to this: the option to give you the behavior you want is set as follows:

   ```
   setopt noappendhistory
   ```

   Add this command to your `~/.zshrc` file using your favorite editor. Once you've done that, `source` this file as follows:

   ```
   % . ~/.zshrc 
   -- OR --
   % source ~/.zshrc
   ```

Comment: @jaume: I appreciate the edit. I didn't know this was how the upgrade managed the switch from `bash` to `zsh` as Catalina was pre-installed on the machine I bought. One question though: Did you really intend to use the opening sentence in both the 1st and 2nd paragraphs?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and sorry about that. When reviewing a suggested edit, I sometimes copy the original text to the edited post to compare them. I forgot to clean it up after the edit. Feel free to correct such editing mistakes, it's your answer after all :-)

Comment: @jaume: Thanks. In reviewing all of this, I don't doubt that an upgraded Catalina may prompt a user before making a switch to `zsh`. However, the OP didn't mention this. In fact, the only suggestion that it **was** switched to `zsh` is his acceptance of this answer - which states he did *as my *assumption**. But more to the point, it doesn't strike me that  **how** he got to `zsh` (assuming he did) makes a huge amount of difference in the answer. I'd suggest a less extensive edit may cover this. Please take one more look & let me know if you disagree.

Comment: I understand your point. The suggested edit wanted to make it clear that upgrading to Catalina doesn't switch the default shell to `zsh`. Your reviewed answer respects that intention and is fine with me, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes the question concerns the behavior of the **command history** function in `zsh`.

I feel two points should be made before proposing an answer:

1. Information available online for `zsh` often refers to a *"default configuration"*. As far as macOS is concerned, the `zsh` *"default configuration"* may differ from that described in other sources. The *"macOS default configuration"* is the `zsh` *"default configuration"* as modified by `/etc/zshrc`. It's best to review this file before making changes, **AND** all changes should be made in the local user's `~/.zshrc` file.
2. It helps (me at least) to understand that the shell can maintain two (2) **command histories**. One is a **history file** (by default: `~/.zsh_history`), the other one is a **session history** that is cached or retained in memory for each session. The parameters **`SAVEHIST`** and **`HISTSIZE`** determine the depth of the **history file**, and the **session history**, respectively. This can be confusing, and the figure below, while not technically accurate, may help in understanding the concept.

For each *session*, there is a unique **session history**. However, there is (by default) only one **file history** for all sessions. Under the macOS default configuration (ref. `/etc/zshrc`): **`HISTSIZE=2000`**, **`SAVEHIST=1000`**. When a new session is started, the **session history** is empty. However, assuming the **file history** is not empty, pressing the up arrow key (<kbd>⬆︎</kbd>) will reveal commands issued from other sessions. As time goes on - as commands are issued in this new session - its **session history** will begin filling commands entered in this new session. After, say, 20 commands have been issued, the up arrow (<kbd>⬆︎</kbd>) will reveal those 20 commands; the next up arrow key press will reveal the latest entry in the **file history**.

[image]

In summary: In a **new session** under the macOS default configuration (**`HISTSIZE=2000`**, **`SAVEHIST=1000`**) your **command history** is drawn from the **history file**, which is to say from the **session histories** of other sessions. As more commands are issued in this new session, these session commands will "push" commands from the history file further down in the stack.

As I understand your question, you do not wish your **session histories** to [co-mingle](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/comingle). That is, for any session, you do not want to see any **command history** from another session - from the **history file**. After reading the above, if this is the behavior you want, here is one way to do that:

#### Proposed Answer: Set `SAVEHIST=0` and `HISTSIZE=2000`

Open the file `~/.zshrc` in your editor, and add the following two lines which override the macOS defaults:

> SAVEHIST=0
> HISTSIZE=2000

**`SAVEHIST=0`** will prevent any session from saving its history to the **history file**. Each session will have a **command history** consisting only of its unique **session history**. The up and down arrow keys (<kbd>⬆︎</kbd>, <kbd>⬇︎</kbd>) will **never** show a command from another session because as far as the current session is concerned, that history does not exist. Potentially undesirable side effects of this option are:

- new sessions have no command history
- if a session is closed or terminates, **command history** is lost, but see Note 4 below.

If you tend to keep sessions open for long periods of time (as I do), you could set `HISTSIZE` to a larger value to postpone "pruning" when the history reaches 120% of its allocation (2,400 commands in this case).

If you wish to retain the **history file**,`zsh` provides a [large number of options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) for controlling how the **history file** and **session history** are maintained, and how they interact with each other to present your **command history**. In addition the [`fc` commands](https://shapeshed.com/unix-fc/) are shell *built-ins* that allow manipulation of the  the **command history** (*see also: [1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fc-command-linux-examples/), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544815/286615), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236261/286615)*). Beyond the options native to `zsh` are numerous 3rd party tools dedicated to the **command history** function - even a [tool that stores command history and related tidbits in a relational database](https://github.com/larkery/zsh-histdb). I would summarize by saying, "The *shell command history* suffers from an [*embarrassment of riches*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+embarrassment+of+riches)."

---

### Notes:

1. Note that the name `~/.zsh_history` is not a **standard** for `zsh` - it is simply the filename that Apple has chosen.
2. Apple defines their defaults for `zsh` in the file `/etc/zshrc`. It's instructive to review these, but it's probably best to make changes to the defaults within your local configuration file at `~/.zshrc`.
3. **HISTFILE**, **HISTSIZE** and **SAVEHIST** are covered in the `zshparam` manuals

   > **HISTFILE** (from `man 1 zshparam`)
   > The file to save the history in when  an  interactive  shell exits. If unset, the history is not saved.
   >
   > **HISTSIZE**  (from `man zshparam`)
   > The maximum number of events stored in the internal history list.
   >
   > **SAVEHIST** (from `man zshparam`)
   > The maximum number of history events to save in the history file.
4. The [`fc` commands](https://shapeshed.com/unix-fc/) are shell *built-ins* that allow manipulation of the  the **command history** (*see also: [1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fc-command-linux-examples/), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544815/286615), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236261/286615)*).